# Async/Await - not awaiting the async method

Tags: async-await

Below is my code. Compiler gives warning because AddLog is not awaited. I do not want to await this call and want to continue executing next lines. I dont have any concern if the exception is consumed also. Is it fine to ignore the warning?

```
public async Task Add()
{
    this.AddLog( "Add executing" );

    // Logic to Add Customer
}

public async Task AddLog( string message )
{
    // Write to DB
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to await? What if the `AddLog` method throws exception? you don't want to care about it either?

Comment: Yes, I do not care if AddLog throws exception. I just want to continue executing the other code.

Comment: If it throws, it might take down your application. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you truly want to call the `AddLog` method in a fire-and-forget way, then you have a few options.

If, by design, you want `AddLog` to ***always*** be invoked as a fire-and-forget method, then you could change the signature to not return a `Task`.

```
public async void AddLog( string message ) // change Task to void
{
    // Write to DB
    // WARNING: Make sure that exceptions are handled in here.
}
```

However, if you do this, you better make sure that exceptions are properly handled from within the `AddLog` method.  If any exception goes unhandled, it will crash your process.

Another option is to change the way you invoke `AddLog` to clearly state your intent that you don't care about when the `Task` completes, or about any exceptions that may be raised.  You can do this by defining an empty continuation (Well, almost empty. See my edit at the bottom of the post for why it's a good idea to read the `Task.Exception` property at the very least).

```
// see EDIT for why the Task.Exception property is read here.
this.AddLog("Add executing").ContinueWith(t => { var observed = t.Exception; });
```

With either option, unless you are awaiting on other code inside your `Add` method that you are not showing us, then there is no longer any point in defining your `Add` method as `async`.  You can simply turn it into a regular synchronous method.  Otherwise, you'll then get another warning telling you that `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously...`.

```
public void Add() // no need for "async Task"
{
    // see EDIT for why the Task.Exception property is read here.
    this.AddLog("Add executing").ContinueWith(t => { var observed = t.Exception; });

    // Logic to Add Customer
}
```

In any case, I wouldn't simply ignore the warning.  Much like sometimes we get the warning `Use of unassigned local variable 'x'` in cases where we know that our code is fine, we typically don't ignore the warning.  Instead, we may explicitly initialize the variable to `null` just to make our intent clear, and make the warning go away.  Similarly, you can make the warning go away by making your intentions more explicit to the compiler using one of the above options.

**EDIT: Word of caution about unobserved exceptions**

I should also mention that even with the `ContinueWith` option, you may have to be careful about unhandled exceptions that come from your `AddLog` method.

According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx), the way *unobserved exceptions* from tasks are handled has changed between .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.  So, if you are still running .NET 4.0, or if you forcing .NET 4.0 exception behavior via configuration, you run the risk that unhandled exceptions will crash your process whenever the task gets GC-collected and finalized.

To make sure that this is not a problem, you can adjust the continuation to explicitly ***observe*** the exception, if any is present.  You don't actually need to do anything with it, you just need to read it. This is one way to do it safely:

```
this.AddLog("Add executing").ContinueWith(t => { var observed = t.Exception; });
```

I've updated my earlier examples above to use the safer version of the continuation.

Answer (score 0):

I would make add() non async since it isn't...and then task.run on add log

Comment: Why would this improve the situation?

Comment: Var task = this.addlog.  Then at the end of the method await task.  That might be better for u